# @types/tabulator-tables breaking tabulator-tables import

Tags: angular, typescript, tabulator, definitelytyped

Installing the following (as of tabulator-tables@4.9.1):

```
npm install tabulator-tables
npm install @types/tabulator-tables
```

And then doing the following import

```
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';
```

Results in an error: `Module Usage (Error node_modules @types tabulator tables index.d.ts' is not a module)`.

Using this import instead

```
import 'tabulator-tables';
```

outputs no error, and allows type information to be loaded, but at runtime (e.g., on an Angular 12 project) doesn't actually allow access to the Tabulator object, resulting in errors like `ReferenceError: Tabulator is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the lack of a default export in the type definition file in `@types/tabulator-tables`. Unfortunately, adding a default export upstream isn't feasible because it would break existing codebases.

Luckily there's a workaround for this, [described here](https://github.com/Jojoshua/TypedTabulator/wiki/Module-Usage--(Error--node_modules-@types-tabulator-tables-index.d.ts%27-is-not-a-module)): create an `index.d.ts` file if you haven't already, and add the following line to it:

```
declare module "tabulator-tables" { export = Tabulator; }
```

(Be sure to also make sure the `index.d.ts` file is included by listing it in `"files"` or making sure it's matched by a pattern in `"includes"` in your tsconfig.json. You may also need to set `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `"compilerOptions"`.)